# Need the help for $ \large \sqsubset $ and $\large \sqsupset $

Tags: symbols, fontsize, math-operators

I need `\sqsubset` and `\sqsupset` in larger size. That means `$ \sqsubset  G_n \sqsupset $` for the purpose of completely lies in side the text within the interval of that open and closed space.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

[image]

The symbols are obtained through these definitions (need `graphicx` package):

```
\newcommand{\bigsqsubset}{\mathrel{\text{\scalebox{1.5}{$\sqsubset$}}}}
\newcommand{\bigsqsupset}{\mathrel{\text{\scalebox{1.5}{$\sqsupset$}}}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\bigsqsubset}{\mathrel{\text{\scalebox{1.5}{$\sqsubset$}}}}
\newcommand{\bigsqsupset}{\mathrel{\text{\scalebox{1.5}{$\sqsupset$}}}}

\begin{document}

$ \bigsqsubset  G_n \bigsqsupset $

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the meaning of this, but you can try with `relsize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,relsize}

\newcommand{\fancybrackets}[1]{%
  \mathopen{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sqsubset}}}%
  #1%
  \mathclose{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sqsupset}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\fancybrackets{G_{n}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]